# MPAndroidChart - How can I best set the X-axis values as strings/dates?

Tags: java, android

I'm just a bit lost with this [MPAndroid chart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

I began the beginner example [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Getting-Started), which recommends creating an array/list of objects with getValueX() and getValueY() methods, which you would then add as entries, like this:

```
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>(); // entry list    

for(ValueAndDateObject data : valueAndDateArrayList){ 

    // valueAndDateArrayList is the list of my own data 
    //(objects with a String X-value, and a double Y-value)

    entries.add(new Entry(data.getValueX(), data.getValueY())); //error here
 }
```

There's an error there because Entry only takes (float x, float y). Obviously I can cast the double as a float, but I need the x-axis to have dates not floats. So I did some more searching and found a lot of Github issues about it, but the solutions there I can't seem to understand. Most point to something like [this in the docs](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface). The problem I'm having is I don't understand how this gets applied to the Entry(float x, float y) issue. I can't find when/where the docs/solutions say to apply to Entry().

So when I look at the example about creating the formatter and then setting it, I don't get where the entries.add(new Entry()) stuff comes in. Does that technique replace it? Do I somehow pass it in?

For reference, here's my full method, designed after the beginner example mentioned previously.

```
public void updateUI(final ArrayList<ValueAndDateObject> valueAndDateArrayList){
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();



    for(ValueAndDateObject data : valueAndDateArrayList){

    /** for the sake of the example, let's say there's only one 
    *   ValueAndDataObject in the list and getValueX() returns "02-27-2016"
    *   and getValueY() returns 12,345.0
    */

        entries.add(new Entry(data.getValueX(), data.getValueY())); //error obviously 
    }        

    // would I add the formatter somewhere in here? And what would I "add" it to?

    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Label");
    dataSet.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
    lineChart.setData(lineData);
    lineChart.invalidate();
}
```

From what I can tell, I'll have to make my own formatter class, which I'll model off of the string[] example in the formatter doc link. My hang up is on the "Setting the formatter" section. Just not sure about how that will change/interact with the Entry(float x, float y) issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to treat your `Date` as a timestamp when creating the `Entry` object, e.g.:

```
entries.add(new Entry(new Long(data.getDate().getTime()).floatValue(), new Double(data.getValueY()).floatValue()));
```

In the above, we assume that `data.getDate()` returns a `java.util.Date` and that `data.getValueY()` returns a `double`.

Then all you have to do in your `IAxisValueFormatter` is to convert the timestamp representation back to a `Date` and then into something human readable, like so:

```
public class DateValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        // Simple version. You should use a DateFormatter to specify how you want to textually represent your date.
        return new Date(new Float(value).longValue()).toString();
    }
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Setting the value formatter:

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new DateValueFormatter());
```

**UPDATE:**

User 'Yasir-Ghunaim' provides a very good step-by-step guide as a response in [this thread on github](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/789).

Comment: Thank you, but I still feel like I'm missing something. I've created the formatter as ChartDateFormatter.java, with the code in your snippit. But where do I apply this to the entries method? Or do I apply it to the Line Chart's layout id? I see that we have the entries.add() method in one Activity, and I see that we have the custom formatter as another class...I just don't get how they connect

Comment: @therealccarter that's explained in the documentation [you linked yourself](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface#setting-the-formatter)

Comment: Alright so I see how they passed in the values (String array) to the formatter, missed that when I was reading it. But this would mean that I would be doing the x and y axis separately, and wouldn't have to be using the entries method at all? I could just create an x-value arraylist and a y axis arraylist and pass each into their respective formatters?

Comment: @therealccarter the example may be a little confusing. You shouldn't pass your data set to the value formatter. The underlying mechanics will take of invoking the getFormattedValue(...) for each of your x values.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me! I'm still just a bit behind you here, here's my code on codeshare, maybe you could give me some pointers here? https://codeshare.io/Gk0wEA

Comment: @therealccarter If your issue is the line `entries.add(new Entry(date, data.getValueY())); // still errors` then that's because you're not converting your date to a timestamp (i.e. a `long`) and casting that to a `double` value. See the top-most code snippet in my answer.

Comment: Same old errors after going to long then double: https://codeshare.io/Gk0wEA. Tbh I'm just going to find another library, I simply want to graph some dates and values, I really don't need something this time consuming lol. Thanks again for all your help @Janus Varmaken

Comment: @therealccarter well in that case it must be that your `data.getValueY()` doesn't return a double? I've used this library (though the iOS clone called Charts) to plot pain levels (scale of 0-10) as y coordinates against date/time stamps as x coordinates.

Comment: @therealccarter Ah sorry, my mistake, I didn't realize that the Entry constructor expects floats, not doubles. Well in that case it's quite simple: instead of converting both the timestamp and the y-value to doubles, you need to convert them to floats instead.

Comment: @therealccarter I edited the answer so that the proper type (float, not double) is passed to the Entry constructor. However, be aware that there is a possibility that you get incorrect results in case of float overflow.

Comment: Thanks, and just to wrap it up for now: I would write the conversion from float to the string/date that I want inside of the custom formatter getFormattedValue() method and return it?

Comment: @therealccarter yes the value returned from `getFormattedValue` is the string that will appear as the x-value on the x-axis. So first construct a `Date` instance from the `float` value (by first converting it back to a `long`), and then return the string representation of that `Date` in your desired format using a `DateFormatter`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this might just be solved. I'll keep working on it to make sure and then I'll check this answer as the solution